# Appium inspector not recognizing iOS elements or refreshing

Tags: ios, appium, appium-ios, ui-testing

I am unable to use the Apppium Inspector in iOS.

When I load a desired capability set into Appium Inspector the app loads fine as shown below

[image]

I am unable to do anything after that point though. Issues..

1. The Login button automatically shows "Interactions are not available for this element" after it initially loads
2. When I click on the Login button in the simulator the simulator goes to the next screen, but when I refresh the Inspector nothing happens. It stays on the blue screen.

This same process works fine for Android and inspecting elements, moving through screens etc.

Specs:

```
Macbook Pro M1 - Monterey 12.2

Appium version: 1.22.3

iOS simulator version: 15.4
```

The Appium server logs just seem to repeat the same lines over and over during this process:

```
[W3C (eae40a9e)] Responding to client with driver.getTimeouts() result: {"command":3600000,"implicit":0} 
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/eae40a9e-623e-4274-bdf6-77165c5562f0/timeouts 304 1 ms - -
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/eae40a9e-623e-4274-bdf6-77165c5562f0/timeouts
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (eae40a9e)] Calling AppiumDriver.getTimeouts() with args: ["eae40a9e-623e-4274-bdf6-77165c5562f0"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getTimeouts'
[W3C (eae40a9e)] Responding to client with driver.getTimeouts() result: {"command":3600000,"implicit":0}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/eae40a9e-623e-4274-bdf6-77165c5562f0/timeouts 304 3 ms - -
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/eae40a9e-623e-4274-bdf6-77165c5562f0/timeouts
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (eae40a9e)] Calling AppiumDriver.getTimeouts() with args: ["eae40a9e-623e-4274-bdf6-77165c5562f0"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getTimeouts'
[W3C (eae40a9e)] Responding to client with driver.getTimeouts() result: {"command":3600000,"implicit":0}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/eae40a9e-623e-4274-bdf6-77165c5562f0/timeouts 304 6 ms - -
[HTTP]
```

Answer (score 3):

Downgrading the iOS simulator version from 15.4 to 15.0 seems to have solved the issue.  I am not going to mark this as accepted yet though in case someone else has a better solution

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/110911

Answer (score 0):

After upgrade to latest appium server & appium inspector. it worked fine for me.

Ref:https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/16828